# Not able to run python file from conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, environment, miniconda

I am not able to run the python file after activating the conda environment in the folder where the python file is.

Below is the screenshot of the error that i am getting after running the python file:-

[image]

Below is the screenshot of the folder in which the conda environment and all the other files including python ones are:-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `/bin/python3` is using the system-level Python, not the one in the environment. Instead, use plain "`python`" and let the PATH resolve the environment's Python binary.

Or, use `conda run`, which I find is preferable for programmatic execution within a Conda environment. See `conda run --help`.

```
conda run -n PB_2870 python "/path/to/file/script.py"
```